# Rank and sales details of a specific company along with top 5 companies in the market

Tags: powerbi, dax

I wants to make a table in Power BI to show rank and sales of Top 5 companies for a product category. If the targetted company is included in top 5 ranks, it should show the top 5 companies only: shown as below
[image]

If the company is out of top 5, then top 5 should be shown, along with that as 6th row, the details of the specific company as shown below.
[image]

Im able to show the top 5 comapnies but not able to include the company as 6th row if it is out of top 5.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

First, add a calculated column to the table:

```
Sales Rank = 
RANKX(
    ALL('CompanySales'),
    [Sales],,
    DESC)
```

And then you can use that column in your calculated table to show just the rows you want:

```
Top 5 OR Specific Co = 
FILTER('CompanySales',
    OR( 
        [Company]="Specific Company",
        [Sales Rank]<=5
        )
)
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply, Will this calculated table for top 5 + specific company change according to my slicer/ filter selections. Like product category, dates. I would like to have that

Comment: It should. What happened when you tried it?